# The method createGraphics(float, float) from the type PdfContentByte is deprecated

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

The method createGraphics(float, float) from the type PdfContentByte is deprecated which is alternate method for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `iText`'s JavaDoc

> Gets a Graphics2D to write on. The graphics are translated to PDF
> commands as shapes. No PDF fonts will appear.
>
> Deprecated: use the
> constructor in PdfGraphics2D

Comment: Thanks, I added 
   Graphics2D g2 = new PdfGraphics2D(contentByte, 500, 500); this line its works fine for me